# Convert BitMap to string without line breaks?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, encode, delphi-xe7

Somewhere I found this code to convert a BitMap to a string:

```
function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Input: TBytesStream;
  Output: TStringStream;
begin
  Input := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Input);
    Input.Position := 0;
    Output := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeStream(Input, Output);
      Result := Output.DataString;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, this gives back a block of wrapped lines. Is it possible to get one single line without line breaks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XE7 introduces the [`System.NetEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding) unit which contains a base64 encoder. This is intended to be used rather than the encoder from `Soap.EncdDecd`.

The [constructor of `TBase64Encoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding.Create) has overloads that allow you to specify characters per line (and line break text). Unfortunately Embarcadero haven't deigned to provide documentation yet so we need to read the source to work out what exactly to pass. Having done that, it becomes clear that line breaks are inserted only if the number of characters per line is strictly positive. So create an encoding object like this:

```
Encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
```

Once you have a suitable encoding object use [`Encode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.Encode) to encode your stream of bytes to text. And [`Decode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.Decode) to reverse the process.

That could look like this:

```
function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Input: TBytesStream;
  Output: TStringStream;
  Encoding: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  Input := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Input);
    Input.Position := 0;
    Output := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      Encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
      try
        Encoding.Encode(Input, Output);
        Result := Output.DataString;
      finally
        Encoding.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure BitmapFromBase64(Base64: string; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  Input: TStringStream;
  Output: TBytesStream;
  Encoding: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  Input := TStringStream.Create(Base64, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    Output := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
      Encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
      try
        Encoding.Decode(Input, Output);
        Output.Position := 0;
        Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Output);
      finally
        Encoding.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively you can use [`EncodeBytesToString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.EncodeBytesToString) and [`DecodeStringToBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.DecodeStringToBytes). Which might look like this:

```
function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Stream: TBytesStream;
  Encoding: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  Stream := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Stream);
    Encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
    try
      Result := Encoding.EncodeBytesToString(Copy(Stream.Bytes, 0, Stream.Size));
    finally
      Encoding.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure BitmapFromBase64(Base64: string; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  Stream: TBytesStream;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  Encoding: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  Stream := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Encoding := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
    try
      Bytes := Encoding.DecodeStringToBytes(Base64);
      Stream.WriteData(Bytes, Length(Bytes));
      Stream.Position := 0;
      Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    finally
      Encoding.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What would be really good would be if we could have something like the compression and decompression streams that are available with zlib. We could create an encoding stream, save the bitmap to it, and read out the base64 text. In the other direction we'd feed base64 text into a decoding stream, and then load the bitmap from it. This should really be part of the `NetEncoding` unit, but it would be simple enough to add as a class helper.

Comment: David, following your advice, I've added the changed code. Is this correct? This outputs 1440 characters for a 16 x 16 pixel bitmap. Is there a way to decrease the number of characters?

Comment: 1440 sounds right, assuming 32bpp. Compress the image if you want to reduce size.

Comment: Does compressing also reduce quality?

Comment: Depends how you do it. PNG won't.

Comment: I think you can use fewer streams. A byte stream and then `EncodeBytesToString` would do it.

Comment: Using EncodeBytesToString increases the size of the output string from 1440 to 10924 characters!

Comment: You need to slice the byte stream. I can see you need more help. Please wait a minute and I'll add some code to demonstrate.

Comment: OK, I wrote some code to show you the various options. I hope that suffices.

Comment: David, thank you for the code, I was away for lunch. Who could write such a compressing class helper?

Comment: Well, I think I could, but when I wrote "simple", I meant, "feasible". It would take a deal of effort to get it right.

Comment: What could motivate you to write such a class helper?

Comment: I don't know. I'm a little busy at the moment. If I get time, and can make something work, I'll let you know.

Comment: That would be very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

`Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeStream()` is hard-coded to output a line break every 75 characters.  The only way to change that is to make a copy of `Soap.EncdDecd.pas`, edit it, and then add the copy to your project (and this approach does not work if your project has Runtime Packages enabled).

You can use Indy's `TIdEncoderMIME` class as an alternative.  It does not output line breaks:

```
uses
  ..., IdCoderMIME;

function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Input: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Input := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Input);
    Input.Position := 0;
    Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(Input);
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;
```