# Is there a function in delphi to base64 encode a string without CRLF?

Tags: delphi

Is there a function in delphi to base64 encode a string without CRLF? I try TnetEncoding.Base64.Encode(MyStr) but the result string contain CRLF (linebreak)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is: `TBase64Encoding` constructed with specific parameters. There are three different constructor overloads. Default `TNetEncoding.Base64` instance is constructed with default one. With other two constructors you can specify how many characters will be per line as well as line separator.

```
constructor Create; overload; virtual;
constructor Create(CharsPerLine: Integer); overload; virtual;
constructor Create(CharsPerLine: Integer; LineSeparator: string); overload; virtual;
```

If you specify empty string as new line delimiter, result will not have new line characters.

```
var
  s, Encoded: string;
  Base64: TBase64Encoding;

  s := 'Some larger text that needs to be encoded in Base64 encoding';
  Base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(10, '');
  Encoded := Base64.Encode(s);
```

Output:

```
U29tZSBsYXJnZXIgdGV4dCB0aGF0IG5lZWRzIHRvIGJlIGVuY29kZWQgaW4gQmFzZTY0IGVuY29kaW5n
```

---

There is a better solution for no breaks at all provided in David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826182/4267244)

Using second constructor and passing `0` as parameter omits line breaks.

```
Base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
```

Comment: Specifying that a new line should be started every 10 characters, using nothing as the line separator, seems less elegant than specifying that no new line should be started. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826182, you can pass `0` for `CharsPerLine` for that.

Comment: @hvd 10 is used just as example, so behavior can be more easily observed.. I admit I didn't dig that deep into the source to observe behavior David did...

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own function for this. It's really simple:

```
function EncodeBase64(const Input: TBytes): string;
const
  Base64: array[0..63] of Char =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

  function Encode3Bytes(const Byte1, Byte2, Byte3: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[((Byte1 shl 4) or (Byte2 shr 4)) and $3F]
      + Base64[((Byte2 shl 2) or (Byte3 shr 6)) and $3F]
      + Base64[Byte3 and $3F];
  end;

  function EncodeLast2Bytes(const Byte1, Byte2: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[((Byte1 shl 4) or (Byte2 shr 4)) and $3F]
      + Base64[(Byte2 shl 2) and $3F] + '=';
  end;

  function EncodeLast1Byte(const Byte1: Byte): string;
  begin
    Result := Base64[Byte1 shr 2]
      + Base64[(Byte1 shl 4) and $3F] + '==';
  end;

var
  i, iLength: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  iLength := Length(Input);
  i := 0;
  while i < iLength do
  begin
    case iLength - i of
      3..MaxInt:
        Result := Result + Encode3Bytes(Input[i], Input[i+1], Input[i+2]);
      2:
        Result := Result + EncodeLast2Bytes(Input[i], Input[i+1]);
      1:
        Result := Result + EncodeLast1Byte(Input[i]);
    end;
    Inc(i, 3);
  end;
end;
```

Using with a string:

```
EncodeBase64(BytesOf(MyStr));
```

Comment: This saved me in Delphi XE5. I was using DCPcrypt v2.0, which is great but somehow it generates a different (bigger) string, and this one is exactly what I need.

Comment: @cdsaenz you're welcome ))

Comment: Since XE7 you can use this method `TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString`from the unit `System.NetEncoding`.